# Remove Content-Disposition and Content-Type from request body using angular-file-upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-file-upload

I'm using https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload for my file uploads.

However, I see that the upload body is like this -

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryXjCfky7muJb4rrZu
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="dump.rdb"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundaryXjCfky7muJb4rrZu--
```

This makes the request size(`Content-Length` header) more than the file size. My server needs the fileSize as header, but also needs it to be same as the request body size. How can I either -

a) Tell angular-file-upload to only send file in body, without adding any other data

b) If a) is not possible, Get the `Content_length` header before upload

Comment: so, you want either no header data, or the content-length header to include the length of the header? So, you're not actually connecting to a HTTP server, right?

Comment: I don't want header data in request body. If that's not possible then I would want to read(in JS) the content-length header before uploading to server, so that I can update the custom fileSize header according to that

Comment: `I don't want header data in request body` well, it isn't there, the header is not in the body, it's in the header

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by setting this on fileItem  -

```
disableMultipart: true
```

It's covered in this PR on angular-file-upload https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/pull/602